# How to hide soft keyboard when listbox is scrolled?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In WP8, how to hide the soft keyboard when the listbox is scrolled?

Is there an event to detect when the listbox is scrolled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I duplicated your problem in a Windows Phone 8 application.

I tested this solution and it does in fact work.

What you want to do is target the `ListBox.ManipulationStarted` event

Inside this event just simply do `this.Focus();`

This will cause the soft keyboard to retreat

Your final product might look like this

```
public page2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        lb.Items.Add(x);

    }
    lb.ManipulationStarted += lb_ManipulationStarted;
}

void lb_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus();
}
```

So my round about way of answering your question is no, there is no scroll event for the listbox. Anything you do will be a hack similar to this but it DOES work.